# The word "Wikipedia" does not hyphenate

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

In my Tex, the word "Wikipedia" does not break down in the end of lines, therefore I always have "overfull hbox" problem.

Details:

```
it is a loooo-
oooo word

it is a long Wikipedia 
word
```

In the second case, the word "Wikipedia" does not break down automatically, so the line is too long.

How could I fix the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Depending on the language in use, have you added possible breakpoints (using babel shorthands or TeX default)?

Comment: Hello, I am using ACM conference template without adding any babel support.

Comment: Please provide Minimum Working Example so it is easier to see what is happening.

Comment: Just add `\hyphenation{wiki-pedia}` before `\begin{document}`. However, since “encyclopedia” is hyphenated as `en-cy-clo-pe-dia`, you may want to do `\hyphenation{wiki-pe-dia}`

Comment: @egreg: why don't you add that as an answer, so we're cutting down on the list of unanswered questions?

Comment: I would advice against hyphenating names, which Wikipedia is. However, some might argue that since it is so commonly attributed to all things wiki, I guess one could under some circumstances hyphenate it.

Comment: Allow me a collateral remark: if you are in doubt whether or not LaTeX is capable of hyphenating a certain word, you can use the `\showhyphens` command, that displays on the terminal all the hyphens that TeX can find.  For example, `\showhyphens{encyclopedia}` displays `en-cy-clo-pe-dia`, whereas `\showhyphens{wikipedia}` gives `wikipedia`, showing that no hyphens are found.  @RunarTrollet: there is also the `\uchyph` primitive that addresses the issue you mentioned (_The TeXbook_, p. 454, second “double dangerous bend”).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's true that by default “Wikipedia” is not hyphenated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia

\end{document}
```

[image]

Solution: add `\hyphenation{wiki-pe-dia}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\hyphenation{wiki-pe-dia} % like en-cy-clo-pe-dia

\begin{document}

wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia
wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia wikipedia

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `babel` is used, the appropriate command is

```
\babelhyphenation{wiki-pe-dia}
```

which will set the hyphenation for all declared languages.

Comment: Why not `wi-ki-pe-dia`?

Comment: @KRyan I don't like to split “Wi-kipedia”, but that's just personal preference. I can tell you that Barbara Beeton has added the hyphenation `wiki-pe-dia` to the list of exception. See chat discussion at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31160649#31160649

Comment: OK, sounds legit but I honestly have no idea what that is.

Comment: @KRyan since "wiki" is Hawaiian and "pedia" is derived from Greek, it's reasonable to *prefer* wiki-pedia. Also, since LaTeX is usually pretty good at formatting a complete paragraph, you don't really need to tell it every possible hyphenation point in a word. There are plenty of 4 and 5 letter English words that can't be hyphenated, so adding another two isn't going to hurt much. In fact there are even 9-letter English words with only one syllable, for example "strengths", so being unable to hyphenate "Wikipedia" at all isn't *usually* a problem for LaTeX...

Comment: @KRyan ... and you want to avoid hyphens that mislead the reader. "wikipe-..." might be misread with a long I and a silent E, but it's not as bad as "the-rapist" or "wee-knights".

Comment: @alephzero Excellent points all around, I appreciate the education.

Comment: All of these points are accurate, but from a raw typesetting perspective, which is where we get hyphenation at the end of a work, it should be able to break down at any point between syllables, so long as it leaves more than one character wrapped to the next line.  It may be reasonable to prefer wiki-pedia, but then don't use the example of en-cy-clo-pe-dia, which is hyphenated "correctly".  I agree that wiki-pedia is completely reasonable, but it's also reasonable to prefer true syllabic hyphenation as well.

Comment: @JesseWilliams What should be the syllabic hyphenation? `wi-` would not fit, I guess.

Comment: wi-ki-pe-dia, just like en-cy-clo-pe-dia.  I'm not fond of it, and for my own use would probably try to break it down as wiki-pe-dia or wiki-pedia, but I can't abide by the idea that because of disparate roots the word somehow takes on a magical transformative property.  Wikipedia wasn't even a word until a very short time ago - it can play by English rules easily enough :)

Comment: But, as an aside to that, I would probably override the hyphenation for encyclopedia as well.  The fringe case where you need to parse out two characters prior to hyphenation...  there are other ways to resolve it.

Comment: @JesseWilliams Wouldn't `wi-kipedia` suggest wrong pronunciation, because of the “long i”?

Comment: Sure, and the same argument could be made for ency-clopedia, especially given it's Greek roots, that "clopedia" contains a short-O sound rather than a long-O sound.  Also note that Wikipedia is often pronounced with short-I sounds by native English speakers, much like GIF is often verbalized with both a soft- and hard-G sound by different folks.  Interestingly, even those that pronounce with short-I sounds seem to often use long-I sounds when just saying "wiki".